# Remove null objects from a List of Student objects

Tags: java

I was exploring Java 8 feature to remove null objects from a List of say Student objects and I have the following code

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Objects;

public class Student {

    private String name;

    public Student(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Student {" + "name=" + name + "}";
    }

    public static Comparator<Student> getNameComparator() {

        return (s1, s2) -> s1.name.compareTo(s2.name);
        // return Comparator.comparing(x -> x.name,
        // Comparator.nullsLast(Comparator.naturalOrder()));
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        List<Student> ls = new ArrayList<>(
                Arrays.asList(new Student("Dino"), new Student(null), new Student("Fred"), new Student("Amy")));
        // ls.removeAll(Collections.singleton(null));
        ls.removeIf(Objects::isNull);
        ls.forEach(s -> System.out.println(s));
        System.out.println("...............................");
        ls.sort(Student.getNameComparator());
        ls.forEach(s -> System.out.println(s));

    }

}
```

I have used java 8 specific isNull i.e `ls.removeIf(Objects::isNull);` still in the o/p I see null value 
i.e 
O/p is

> Student {name=Dino} Student {name=null} Student {name=Fred} Student
>   {name=Amy}

Am I missing on something specific ?

Thanks
Ronan

Comment: Just for the record: the much saner approach would be to A) not allow for null Students and B) students with null names in the first place ;-)

Comment: Thanks @GhostCat I agree but just in case if null comes then code should handle it , I wanted to explore Java 8 feature to remove null than using old pre-java 8 style . Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`removeIf(Objects::isNull)` is removing any `Student` object in the given list that is `null`, not every Student whichs `name` is `null`. You can achieve what you want with `.removeIf(student -> student.getName() == null)`

Comment: Just curious to know why ls.removeAll(Collections.singleton(null)); didnt work either

Comment: `removeIf` expects a `Predicate<Student` which means it expects a function that for a given student returns true or false. `removeAll` receives a given `Collection<Student>` and removes all `Student` objects that match any object in the provided collection (in your case `Collections.singleton(null)`). But there is no `null` student, only students with `null` `name`